# How to manage UI Table View in View Controller

Tags: xcode, uiview, cell, tableview, uitableview

I've got a simple UI View, with some items in it. I'd like to place in it a Table View.

Can anybody explain me with easy steps what do I have to write in order to manage it?

I have another UITableView with elements in it, rows etc. The problem is implementing a TableView in a UI View: I don't know how to add rows etc from there.

I tried, with no success, to do the following:

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate> {
UITextField     *indirizzo;
NSMutableData   *data;
UIButton *compra;
```

and then Implementing, in the .m file, the specific methods like

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 10;
}
```

But the table doesn't change.

Comment: can you briefly explain your question....???

Comment: Well, essentially I need to know how to add and manage rows in a Table View located in a UI View Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for start if you want to add rows to a UITableView you need to declare your UIViewController as the tableView **DataSource** not delegate. (delegate is for other stuff)

You should go over the [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH1-SW1)