# How properly add UITableView with prototyped cells in UIView in Interface builder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I try to make `UIViewController` (VC) with `UITableView` (TV) inside it with `custom prototyped cells` (PC). I use mainly Interface Builder. I do follwing steps:

1. I created `VC` and I add `TV` to it in the `Storyboard`.
2. I set `VC` class as delegate to the `TV` using `UITableViewDelegate`.
3. I created `PC` and created custom class for it. I set that class to be custom class for `PC`
4. I added `TV` as outlet to `VC` class code.
5. I added all controls from `PC` as outlets to `PC` custom class.
6. I configured identifier for `PC`. I added all methods of `TV` to `VC` class.

When I run my App the methods for `TV` never start and the `TV` is empty. I am sure that I missed something but I can not figure what. Any ideas?

Comment: 2.a Add VC class as data source TV using UITableViewDataSource.
7. Implement all the table view data source methods inside VC

Comment: I've read that, @Astoria, in answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376946/how-to-manage-ui-table-view-in-view-controller) but I don't know how to do that. So after your comment I find out how to do that. 10x!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement methods of [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html) as well as UITableViewDelegate.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)secion;
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath;
```